# The code block is missing a closing "}" character. MVC razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I need to show the data on the basis on below condition. Need to show 5 columns and then next data in next row. I am new for MVC. Please help.

```
@{
    int count = 0;
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (count == 0) { @:<tr> }
        <td>
            <p align="center">item.WeekNumber</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            item.OpenFirst<br>
            item.OpenSecond<br>
            item.OpenThird
        </td>
        <td><font size="6">OpenResult</font></td>
        <td>
            item.CloseFirst<br>
            item.CloseSecond<br>
            item.CloseThird
        </td>
        if (count == 5) { count = -1; @:</tr> }
        count++;
    }                 
}
```

Comment: what is it that you want to in your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I think the problem is @ on the first foreach loop. Please remove it and try. And one more thing if you want to use html in the Razor code then you can use `@Html.Raw()`. (Example `@Html.Raw("<tr>")`)